# ExpressJS Uploading and Display Image from AWS S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been following the Heroku "[Direct to S3 File Uploads in Node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node)" to be able to upload and display images from my AWS S3 bucket. I made the CORS configuration for the bucket I am using in this project, but I am not seeing any images uploaded to my bucket and am not able to display any images. When I try to console.log my onError method for the file upload, I get `undefined`. I do not run into any errors when I `POST`. Provided below is my code:

eventsModel.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var EventSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    title: String,
    company: String,
    url: String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    speakerImage: String

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);
```

routes.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Event = require('./models/eventsModel');

router.get('/sign_s3', function(req, res){
    aws.config.update({accessKeyId: "My Access Key", secretAccessKey: "My Secret Key"});
    var s3 = new aws.S3();
    var s3_params = {
        Bucket: "My Bucket Name",
        Key: req.query.s3_object_name,
        Expires: 60,
        ContentType: req.query.s3_object_type,
        ACL: 'public-read'
    };
    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3_params, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            var return_data = {
                signed_request: data,
                url: 'https://'+"My Bucket Name"+'.s3.amazonaws.com/'+req.query.s3_object_name
            };
            res.write(JSON.stringify(return_data));
            res.end();
        }
    });
});

router.route('/admin/events/create')

    .post(function(req, res){

        var events = new Event();

        events.name = req.body.name;
        events.title = req.body.title;
        events.company = req.body.company;
        events.url = req.body.url;
        events.speakerImage = req.body.speakerImage;

        events.save(function(err){
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.redirect(303, '/events');

        });
    })

    .get(function(req, res){
        Event.find(function(err, events){
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.render('pages/events-create.ejs');
        });
    });



router.route('/admin/events/:events_id')

    .get(function(req, res){
        Event.findById(req.params.events_id, function(err, events){
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(events);
        });
    })

    .put(function(req, res){

        Event.findById(req.params.events_id, function(err, events){
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Event Updated'});
        });
    });

//GET '/events'
router.get('/events', function(req, res) {
    Event.find({})
        .sort({'date': -1})
        .exec(function(err, events) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        console.log(events.speakerImage);
        console.log(events.name);

        res.render('pages/events.ejs', {
            events : events
        });
    });
});
```

events-create.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
</head>

<body>
    <% include ../partials/navigation %>

<div class="grid" id="create-event-container">
        <div class="col-1-1">
            <div id="create-event">
                <h1><i>Create Event</i></h1>
                <input type="file" id="files"/>
                <p id="status">Please select a file</p>
                <div id="preview"><img src="/images/event-placeholder.png"></div>
                <form action="/admin/events/create" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" id="speaker-image" name="speakerImage" value="public/images/event-placeholder.png" />
                    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
                    Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br>
                    Company: <input type="text" name="company"><br>
                    Website: <input type="text" name="url"><br>
                    Upcoming Event?: <input type="checkbox" name="upcomingEvent"><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/s3upload.js">

    <script>
    function s3_upload(){
        var status_elem = document.getElementById("status");
        var url_elem = document.getElementById("speaker-image");
        var preview_elem = document.getElementById("preview");
        var s3upload = new S3Upload({
            file_dom_selector: 'files',
            s3_sign_put_url: '/sign_s3',
            onProgress: function(percent, message) {
                status_elem.innerHTML = 'Upload progress: ' + percent + '% ' + message;
            },
            onFinishS3Put: function(public_url) {
                status_elem.innerHTML = 'Upload completed. Uploaded to: '+ public_url;
                url_elem.value = public_url;
                preview_elem.innerHTML = '<img src="'+public_url+'" style="width:300px;" />';
            },
            onError: function(status) {
                status_elem.innerHTML = 'Upload error: ' + status;
                console.log(status_elem.innerHTML);
            }
        });
    }
    /*
    * Listen for file selection:
    */
    (function() {
        var input_element = document.getElementById("files");
        input_element.onchange = s3_upload;
    })();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

server.js:

```
//Load Express
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var eventsDb = require('./config/eventsDb');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var aws = require('aws-sdk');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true})); //get data from a POST method
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect(eventsDb.url);

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; //set port

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); //set EJS template engine

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // set the public directory

var AWS_ACCESS_KEY = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY;
var AWS_SECRET_KEY = process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY;
var S3_BUCKET = process.env.S3_BUCKET

var Event = require('./app/models/eventsModel');


var routes = require('./app/routes');
app.use(routes);

app.listen(port);
console.log('access at port:' + port);
```

s3upload.js (Also can be accessed in the repo from the blog article):

```
(function() {

  window.S3Upload = (function() {

    S3Upload.prototype.s3_object_name = 'default_name';

    S3Upload.prototype.s3_sign_put_url = '/signS3put';

    S3Upload.prototype.file_dom_selector = 'file_upload';

    S3Upload.prototype.onFinishS3Put = function(public_url) {
      return console.log('base.onFinishS3Put()', public_url);
    };

    S3Upload.prototype.onProgress = function(percent, status) {
      return console.log('base.onProgress()', percent, status);
    };

    S3Upload.prototype.onError = function(status) {
      return console.log('base.onError()', status);
    };

    function S3Upload(options) {
      if (options == null) options = {};
      for (option in options) {
        this[option] = options[option];
      }
      this.handleFileSelect(document.getElementById(this.file_dom_selector));
    }

    S3Upload.prototype.handleFileSelect = function(file_element) {
      var f, files, output, _i, _len, _results;
      this.onProgress(0, 'Upload started.');
      files = file_element.files;
      output = [];
      _results = [];
      for (_i = 0, _len = files.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        f = files[_i];
        _results.push(this.uploadFile(f));
      }
      return _results;
    };

    S3Upload.prototype.createCORSRequest = function(method, url) {
      var xhr;
      xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      if (xhr.withCredentials != null) {
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
      } else if (typeof XDomainRequest !== "undefined") {
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
      } else {
        xhr = null;
      }
      return xhr;
    };

    S3Upload.prototype.executeOnSignedUrl = function(file, callback) {
      var this_s3upload, xhr;
      this_s3upload = this;
      xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', this.s3_sign_put_url + '?s3_object_type=' + file.type + '&s3_object_name=' + this.s3_object_name, true);
      xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
        var result;
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
          try {
            result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          } catch (error) {
            this_s3upload.onError('Signing server returned some ugly/empty JSON: "' + this.responseText + '"');
            return false;
          }
          return callback(result.signed_request, result.url);
        } else if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status !== 200) {
          return this_s3upload.onError('Could not contact request signing server. Status = ' + this.status);
        }
      };
      return xhr.send();
    };

    S3Upload.prototype.uploadToS3 = function(file, url, public_url) {
      var this_s3upload, xhr;
      this_s3upload = this;
      xhr = this.createCORSRequest('PUT', url);
      if (!xhr) {
        this.onError('CORS not supported');
      } else {
        xhr.onload = function() {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            this_s3upload.onProgress(100, 'Upload completed.');
            return this_s3upload.onFinishS3Put(public_url);
          } else {
            return this_s3upload.onError('Upload error: ' + xhr.status);
          }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function() {
          return this_s3upload.onError('XHR error.');
        };
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
          var percentLoaded;
          if (e.lengthComputable) {
            percentLoaded = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
            return this_s3upload.onProgress(percentLoaded, percentLoaded === 100 ? 'Finalizing.' : 'Uploading.');
          }
        };
      }
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', file.type);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('x-amz-acl', 'public-read');
      return xhr.send(file);
    };

    S3Upload.prototype.uploadFile = function(file) {
      var this_s3upload;
      this_s3upload = this;
      return this.executeOnSignedUrl(file, function(signedURL, publicURL) {
        return this_s3upload.uploadToS3(file, signedURL, publicURL);
      });
    };

    return S3Upload;

  })();

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Can you check what the Safari (or Chrome) Inspector tells you? Look at the Resources tab and check what you see under XHR. Do you see anything that can help debugging?

Comment: XHR is showing the loaded `s3upload.js`. My `POST` method is showing the following properties, speakerImage, name, title, company and url, with the values I provided, but I noticed the the speakerImage path is not correct. `public/image/event-placeholder.png` is the value being passed. This should have been the path of the file I uploaded to S3. It also appears I am getting a 404 when I `GET` public/image/event-placeholder.png

Comment: I'm more interested in the responses from the servers rather than the requests :)

Comment: @Qualcuno, sorry if I am confused. Are you looking for the header information for the s3upload.js that appears under the XHR in my Chrome developer tools?

Comment: I think that if there's something wrong, the first place you need to check is the raw HTTP requests. Check all the XHR requests, and see if there's anything "misplaced": a header, something in the body... Both in the requests and the responses. If you're getting nothing from console.log(), check the response body to see if that contains anything!

Comment: Right, I think I pointed the issue to the fact that the path being passed to `speakerImage` (the property associated with the file upload) is `public/image/event-placeholder.png` which is the default value when we submit the data.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I thought I would spot one error quickly for anybody else (not sure if there are other errors).

In your router.js file, you need to require:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
```

Also make sure that under your User ('Permissions' -> Managed Policies) that AmazonS3FullAccess is attached to your account.